# Accessing arrays in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I feel like this question has to have been asked but for the life of me I cannot find it. I have an array of objects for football play by play data. The array is actually one of objects. Each object encapsulates all data that happens during any given play in a football game. Here is my JSON object:

```
    var playsToAdd = {
    "play":
    [
     {"quarter":""},
     {"drive":""},
     {"down":""},
     {"fieldPos":""},
     {"yardsToGo":""},
     {"yardsGained":""},
     {"playType":""},
     {"playResult":""},
     {"ballSide":""},
     {"oForm":""},
     {"dForm":""},
     {"scoreFSU":""},
     {"scoreOp":""},
     {"playSide":""},
     {"addToDB":""},
     {"players":
      [
       {"name":""},
       {"position":""}
      ]
     }
    ]
   };
```

Here is where I try to add data to the object

```
for(l=0;l<plays.length;l++)
   {
    playsToAdd.play[l].quarter=plays[l].quarter;
    playsToAdd.play[l].drive=plays[l].drive;
    playsToAdd.play[l].down=plays[l].down;
    playsToAdd.play[l].fieldPos=plays[l].fieldPos;
    playsToAdd.play[l].yardsToGo=plays[l].yardsToGo;
    playsToAdd.play[l].yardsGained=plays[l].yardsGained;
    playsToAdd.play[l].playType=plays[l].playType;
    playsToAdd.play[l].playResult=plays[l].playResult;
    playsToAdd.play[l].ballSide=plays[l].ballSide;
    playsToAdd.play[l].oForm=plays[l].oForm;
    playsToAdd.play[l].dForm=plays[l].dForm;
    playsToAdd.play[l].scoreFSU=plays[l].scoreFSU;
    playsToAdd.play[l].scoreOp=plays[l].scoreOp;
    playsToAdd.play[l].playSide=plays[l].playSide;
    playsToAdd.play[l].addToDB=plays[l].addToDB;
    for(m=0;m<plays[l].players.length;m++)
    {
     //playsToAdd[l].players[m].position=plays[l].players[m][1];
     //playsToAdd[l].players[m].name=plays[l].players[m][0];
     playsToAdd.play[l].players[m].name="test";
    }
   }
```

Everything seems to work out fine until I get to the players piece. I actually commented out my object to make sure that wasn't the problem. I get an error `Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined` in regards to `playsToAdd.play[l].players[m].name="test";`. I've looked around this site and others but haven't found anything that speaks to my issue. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please NEVER AGAIN use l as a variable. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that right now, your `playsToAdd` is an array of objects with each object containing one property namely quarter, drive etc..

It should instead be an array of objects, where each object contains all properties for a play namely quarter, drive etc..

Your JSON structure should be like:

```
var playsToAdd = {
    "play":
    [
     {
       "quarter":"",
       "drive":"",
       "down":"",
       "fieldPos":"",
       "yardsToGo":"",
       "yardsGained":"",
       "playType":"",
       "playResult":"",
       "ballSide":"",
       "oForm":"",
       "dForm":"",
       "scoreFSU":"",
       "scoreOp":"",
       "playSide":"",
       "addToDB":"",
       "players":
      [
       {"name":"", "position":""},
       {"name":"", "position":""},
       ...
      ]
     }
    ]
   };
```

This way, you can access/set your data like:

```
playsToAdd.play[x].quarter = 'xyz';
```

and

```
playsToAdd.play[x].players[y].name = 'xyz';
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you run that loop, you haven't defined `playsToAdd.play[l].players` yet.

If you're trying to create a copy of your object, you could just copy it:

```
playsToAdd = plays.slice(0);
```

This creates an exact copy of the `plays` array. That said, I'm not sure if the nested arrays are copied or referenced. Let me know if you have problems with this and I'll be able to help further.